# Link Multiple Auth Providers to an Account react-native

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm new with  react-native-firebase

I want to link the user after login with facebook provider and google provider 
I tried all solutions on the internet but any of them worked.
this is my code

```
const loginUser = await firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword('test@gmail.com','password888').then(async function(userRecord) {
    console.log("Successfully sign in user:", userRecord.user._user);
    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    console.log('current user ',user)
    let linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential=firebase.auth().currentUser.linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID).then(async u=>{
    console.log('linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential u',u)

    }).catch(async (e)=>{
    console.log('linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential error',e)

    })
    console.log('linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential error',linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential)
    /**/
    await firebase.auth().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail('sss@sss.sss')
    .then(async providers => {
      console.log('login index providers',providers)
    }).catch(function(error){
      console.log('login index providers error',error)
    })
  }).catch(async function(error){
    console.log('login error',error,error.email)
    if(error.code=='auth/user-not-found'){
    }else if(error.code=='auth/wrong-password'){
      errorMsg=`${L('password')} ${L('notValid')}`
    }
    if(errorMsg){
      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        ToastAndroid.show(
          errorMsg,
          ToastAndroid.LONG
        )
      } else {
        Alert.alert(
          '',
          errorMsg,
          [{ text: L('close'), style: 'cancel' }]
        )
      }
    }
    console.log("Error sign in user:", error.code);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

`linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential` needs an AuthCredential, in my app I use [react-native-fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) to get the credential(You’ll need to follow their setup instructions).
This function will prompt the user to log into his facebook account and return an AccessToken, then you get the credential from firebase and finally `linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential`.

```
linkToFacebook = () => {
  LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email'])
    .then((result) => {
      if (result.isCancelled) {
        return Promise.reject(new Error('The user cancelled the request'))
      }
      // Retrieve the access token
      return AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
    })
    .then((data) => {
      // Create a new Firebase credential with the token
      const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken)

      // Link using the credential
      return firebase.auth().currentUser.linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      const { code, message } = error
      window.alert(message)
    })
}
```

Comment: `linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential` is now deprecated https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#linkandretrievedatawithcredential